# R (dplyr): find all rows in row-specific range

Tags: r, dplyr, date-range

I have a dataset where each row is identified by a hospitalization id. Each row contains information on the hospitalization id, hospital id where it took place as well as date of admission and date of discharge of the given hospitalization.

I would like to know, for each hospitalization, the id of all other hospitalizations concluded in the 30 days before the beginning of the given hospitalization in the given hospital where it took place.

Below is a simple example of 6 hospitalizations taking place in 2 hospitals.

```
library("tidyverse")

df <- data.frame(hospitalization_id = c(1, 2, 3, 
                                        4, 5, 6),
                 hospital_id = c("A", "A", "A", 
                                 "B", "B", "B"),
                 date_start = as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-12", "2000-01-20",
                                        "2000-02-10", "2000-02-12", "2000-02-12")),
                 date_end = as.Date(c("2000-01-03", "2000-01-18", "2000-01-22",
                                      "2000-02-11", "2000-02-14", "2000-01-17")))
```

I created the dates in the 30-day interval prior to the beginning of each given hospitalization.

```
df_with_date_range <- df %>%
  mutate(date_range1 = date_start - 31,
         date_range2 = date_start - 1)
```

I am trying to write a code that adds a column with all the hospitalizations that took place in this 30-day interval range. My desired output is below:

```
df_final <- df_with_date_range %>%
  filter(hospitalization_id == 3) %>%
  bind_rows(df_with_date_range) %>%
  arrange(hospitalization_id) %>%
  mutate(hospitalization_id_in_range = c(NA, 1, 1, 2, NA, 4, 4))
```

In hospital A:

- there was no hospitalization in the 30-day period before hospitalization 1
- hospitalization 1 took place in the 30-day period before hospitalization 2
- hospitalization 1 & 2 took place in the 30-day period before hospitalization 3

In hospital B:

- there was no hospitalization in the 30-day period before hospitalization 4
- hospitalization 4 took place in the 30-day period before hospitalization 5
- hospitalization 4 took place in the 30-day period before hospitalization 6

Comment: tricky one. nice data.table merge solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[,from:=date_start-30]

df[df,.(hospital_id,
        hospitalization_id = i.hospitalization_id, 
        date_start = i.date_start,
        date_end = i.date_end,
        prev_hospitalization_id = x.hospitalization_id,
        prev_date_start = x.date_start),
      on=.(hospital_id,date_start>=from,date_start<date_start)]

   hospital_id hospitalization_id date_start   date_end prev_hospitalization_id prev_date_start
        <char>              <num>     <Date>     <Date>                   <num>          <Date>
1:           A                  1 2000-01-01 2000-01-03                      NA            <NA>
2:           A                  2 2000-01-12 2000-01-18                       1      2000-01-01
3:           A                  3 2000-01-20 2000-01-22                       1      2000-01-01
4:           A                  3 2000-01-20 2000-01-22                       2      2000-01-12
5:           B                  4 2000-02-10 2000-02-11                      NA            <NA>
6:           B                  5 2000-02-12 2000-02-14                       4      2000-02-10
7:           B                  6 2000-02-12 2000-01-17                       4      2000-02-10
```

The `x` and `i` prefixes refer to the `X[i,j,by]` syntax specific to `data.table`.
This means in the example above that `x` is the outer `df` and `i` the inner `df`.

Comment: This is great, @Waldi! It is much faster!

Comment: I am now trying to adjust this code to consider two other layers of complexity: (i) I would like to match only hospitalizations between physician in the same specialty (a physician can have multiple specialties, I would like to consider the set of hospitalizations in any of the specialty of the physician); (ii) I would like to not consider hospitalizations performed by the reference physician (a hospitalization may involve multiple physicians, in which case I would like to exclude them even if it also involves another physician in the same specialty).

Comment: I posted an example in the link below, and someone proposed an excellent solution - the only issue is that, even though it uses data.frame, it is quite slow to run because for every hospitalization-physician, the code goes over all the rows in the dataset. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379338/find-set-of-rows-in-row-specific-range-with-restriction-at-different-levels/73379633?noredirect=1#comment129611043_73379633

Answer (score 2):

A tidy solution involving filtering of the original data frame and the `between` function:

```r
df_with_date_range %>%
  mutate(hospital_id_in_range = pmap(list(date_range1, date_range2, hospital_id),
                   function(x, y, z) ungroup(filter(rowwise(df_with_date_range),
                                                 between(date_start, x, y),
                                                 hospital_id == z))$hospitalization_id)) %>%
  unnest(hospital_id_in_range, keep_empty = TRUE)

# # A tibble: 7 × 7
#   hospitalization_id hospital_id date_start date_end   date_range1 date_range2 hospital_id_in_range
#                <dbl> <chr>       <date>     <date>     <date>      <date>                     <dbl>
# 1                  1 A           2000-01-01 2000-01-03 1999-12-01  1999-12-31                    NA
# 2                  2 A           2000-01-12 2000-01-18 1999-12-12  2000-01-11                     1
# 3                  3 A           2000-01-20 2000-01-22 1999-12-20  2000-01-19                     1
# 4                  3 A           2000-01-20 2000-01-22 1999-12-20  2000-01-19                     2
# 5                  4 B           2000-02-10 2000-02-11 2000-01-10  2000-02-09                    NA
# 6                  5 B           2000-02-12 2000-02-14 2000-01-12  2000-02-11                     4
# 7                  6 B           2000-02-12 2000-01-17 2000-01-12  2000-02-11                     4
```

Comment: Thanks a million @dcsuka! I added another layer of complexity to this problem. I posted another code here where I refer to this post. It would be great if you could have a look! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73365482/r-dplyr-find-all-rows-in-row-specific-range-with-restriction

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr` and `base`. Relies on `cur_data()` and `uncount`.

```
# functions ---------------------------------------------------------------

get_previous_ids <- function(df) {
  sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) df$hospitalization_id[df$date_start>=df$date_range1[i] & df$date_start<=df$date_range2[i]])
}

add_nas <- function(mylist) {
  lapply(mylist, function(x) {
    res <- x
    if(length(x)==0) res <- NA
    res
  })
}

# mutations ---------------------------------------------------------------

res <- df_with_date_range %>% group_by(hospital_id) %>%
  mutate(prev_id = add_nas(get_previous_ids(cur_data())), 
         nb_ids= sapply(prev_id, length))
         
res %>% ungroup() %>% uncount(nb_ids) %>% group_by(hospitalization_id) %>% 
  mutate(rowid = row_number(), hospitalization_id_in_range=prev_id[[1]][rowid])

    # A tibble: 7 x 9
    # Groups:   hospitalization_id [6]
      hospitalization_id hospital_id date_start date_end   date_range1 date_range2 prev_id   rowid hospitalization_id~
                   <dbl> <chr>       <date>     <date>     <date>      <date>      <list>    <int>               <dbl>
    1                  1 A           2000-01-01 2000-01-03 1999-12-01  1999-12-31  <lgl [1]>     1                  NA
    2                  2 A           2000-01-12 2000-01-18 1999-12-12  2000-01-11  <dbl [1]>     1                   1
    3                  3 A           2000-01-20 2000-01-22 1999-12-20  2000-01-19  <dbl [2]>     1                   1
    4                  3 A           2000-01-20 2000-01-22 1999-12-20  2000-01-19  <dbl [2]>     2                   2
    5                  4 B           2000-02-10 2000-02-11 2000-01-10  2000-02-09  <lgl [1]>     1                  NA
    6                  5 B           2000-02-12 2000-02-14 2000-01-12  2000-02-11  <dbl [1]>     1                   4
    7                  6 B           2000-02-12 2000-01-17 2000-01-12  2000-02-11  <dbl [1]>     1                   4
```