# Find set of rows in row-specific range with restriction at different levels

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, date-range

I have a dataset where each row is identified by a hospitalization id - physician id. Each row also contains information on the dates of admission and discharge and the hospital where it took place. A hospitalization may involve multiple physicians. A physician may work in multiple hospitals.

I have another dataset with information on each physician's specialties (e.g., clinician, cardiologist). A physician may have multiple specialties.

I would like to know, for each hospitalization-physician row, the id of all other hospitalizations concluded in the 30 days prior to the start of that hospitalization which were performed in the same hospital by other physicians *in the same specialty*.

Partly using the solution posted in [R (dplyr): find all rows in row-specific range *WITH RESTRICTION*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73365482/r-dplyr-find-all-rows-in-row-specific-range-with-restriction/73365832?noredirect=1#comment129583140_73365832), I managed to write a code that finds all hospitalizations performed by other physicians in the same hospital in the 30-day period prior to the start of the given hospitalization. For each row, I first found the list of all hospitalizations in the given hospital during the 30-day time period. Then, I found a list that only includes the hospitalizations where the ego physician was involved. Finally, I selected the elements in the first list which are not in the second list.

I would like to adjust the code to find the hospitalizations by other physicians *who share at least one specialty with the ego physician*. Ideally, I would like to change the first step of the code above to find the list of all hospitalizations within the ego physician's set of specialty. Then I can use the rest of the code as it is to subtract from this list the hospitalizations involving the ego physician. The main difficulty here is the fact that a physician may have multiple specialties - otherwise it would just be a matter of including another variable in the filter function.

Below is the code I have now - it does not take into consideration the specialty of the ego physician.

```
df <- data.frame(hospitalization_id = c(1, 2, 3,
                                        1, 2, 3,
                                        4, 5, 
                                        6, 7, 8),
                 hospital_id = c("A", "A", "A", 
                                 "A", "A", "A", 
                                 "A", "A",
                                 "B", "B", "B"),
                 physician_id = c(1, 1, 1, 
                                  2, 2, 2,
                                  3, 3, 
                                  2, 2, 2),
                 date_start = as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-12", "2000-01-20",
                                        "2000-01-01", "2000-01-12", "2000-01-20",
                                        "2000-01-12", "2000-01-20",
                                        "2000-02-10", "2000-02-11", "2000-02-12")),
                 date_end = as.Date(c("2000-01-03", "2000-01-18", "2000-01-22",
                                      "2000-01-03", "2000-01-18", "2000-01-22",
                                      "2000-01-18", "2000-01-22",
                                      "2000-02-11", "2000-02-14", "2000-02-17")))

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    # Generates 30-day time interval before start of given hospitalization 
    date_range1 = date_start - 30,
    date_range2 = date_start - 1,
    # List of all hospitalizations in given hospital, in time interval
    hospid_all = pmap(list(date_range1, date_range2, hospital_id),
                      function(x, y, z) filter(df,
                                               date_end >= x & date_end <= y,
                                               hospital_id == z)$hospitalization_id),
    hospid_all = lapply(hospid_all, unique),
    # List of ego's hospitalizations in given hospital, in time interval
    hospid_ego = pmap(list(date_range1, date_range2, hospital_id, physician_id),
                      function(x, y, z, p) filter(df,
                                                  date_end >= x & date_end <= y,
                                                  hospital_id == z,
                                                  physician_id == p)$hospitalization_id),
    # List of peers' hospitalizations in given hospital, in time interval
    hospid_peer = future_map2(hospid_all, hospid_ego, ~ .x[!(.x %in% .y)])) %>%
  select(-starts_with('date_'), -hospid_all, -hospid_ego) %>% # only keep peers' list of hospitalization
  rename('ego'='physician_id')

df3 <- df2 %>%
  select(hospitalization_id, hospital_id, ego, hospid_peer) %>%
  unnest(hospid_peer, keep_empty = TRUE)

df4 <- df3 %>%
  left_join(select(df, hospitalization_id, physician_id), 
            by=c('hospid_peer'='hospitalization_id')) %>%
  rename(alter = physician_id)
```

The specialty of each physician is informed in this other df. In this example, Physician 2 shares specialty with both Physician 1 and Physician 3, but Physician 1 and Physician 3 do not have any specialty in common.

```
physician_spec <- data.frame(physician_id = c(1, 2, 2, 3),
                      specialty_code = c(100, 100, 200, 200))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two helper functions, `other_mds`, and `f`. The first of these takes a physician id, and returns the physician ids of those with matching specialities. The second takes the hospital id, the physician id, and the start date (i.e. for a particular row in `df`, and return the list of hospitalizations that concluded within the prior 30 days, were in the same hospital, and were conducted by a physician with a matching speciality.

```
other_mds <- function(pid) {
  physician_spec[
    physician_id!=pid & specialty_code %in% physician_spec[physician_id==pid, specialty_code],
    physician_id]
}

f <- function(hid, pid, s) {
  other_phys = other_mds(pid)
  exclude_hosps = df[physician_id == pid, unique(hospitalization_id)]
  df[hospital_id == hid & 
       physician_id %in% other_phys &
       s>date_end &
       (s-date_end)<30 &
       !hospitalization_id %in% exclude_hosps,
     paste0(hospitalization_id, collapse=",")]
}
```

Now, we just apply the function `f` to each row

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setDT(physician_spec)
df[, matches:=f(hospital_id, physician_id,date_start), 1:nrow(df)]
```

Output:

```
    hospitalization_id hospital_id physician_id date_start   date_end matches
                 <num>      <char>        <num>     <Date>     <Date>  <char>
 1:                  1           A            1 2000-01-01 2000-01-03        
 2:                  2           A            1 2000-01-12 2000-01-18        
 3:                  3           A            1 2000-01-20 2000-01-22        
 4:                  1           A            2 2000-01-01 2000-01-03        
 5:                  2           A            2 2000-01-12 2000-01-18        
 6:                  3           A            2 2000-01-20 2000-01-22       4
 7:                  4           A            3 2000-01-12 2000-01-18       1
 8:                  5           A            3 2000-01-20 2000-01-22     1,2
 9:                  6           B            2 2000-02-10 2000-02-11        
10:                  7           B            2 2000-02-11 2000-02-14        
11:                  8           B            2 2000-02-12 2000-02-17
```

#### Update - returning a vector of matches, and then merge:

1. Change `f` so that it returns a vector

```
f <- function(hid, pid, s) {
  other_phys = other_mds(pid)
  exclude_hosps = df[physician_id == pid, unique(hospitalization_id)]
  df[hospital_id == hid & 
       physician_id %in% other_phys &
       s>date_end &
       (s-date_end)<30 &
       !hospitalization_id %in% exclude_hosps]$hospitalization_id
}
```

2. Now, when we run the function, we do this by `hospitalization_id` and `physician_id`, so that it returns a three column data.table (columns are the by columns and new column called `match`. Then merge this on the original df

```
df[, .(match = f(hospital_id, physician_id,date_start)), .(hospitalization_id, physician_id)][
  df, 
  on=.(hospitalization_id,physician_id)
]
```

Output:

```
    hospitalization_id physician_id match hospital_id date_start   date_end
                 <num>        <num> <num>      <char>     <Date>     <Date>
 1:                  1            1    NA           A 2000-01-01 2000-01-03
 2:                  2            1    NA           A 2000-01-12 2000-01-18
 3:                  3            1    NA           A 2000-01-20 2000-01-22
 4:                  1            2    NA           A 2000-01-01 2000-01-03
 5:                  2            2    NA           A 2000-01-12 2000-01-18
 6:                  3            2     4           A 2000-01-20 2000-01-22
 7:                  4            3     1           A 2000-01-12 2000-01-18
 8:                  5            3     1           A 2000-01-20 2000-01-22
 9:                  5            3     2           A 2000-01-20 2000-01-22
10:                  6            2    NA           B 2000-02-10 2000-02-11
11:                  7            2    NA           B 2000-02-11 2000-02-14
12:                  8            2    NA           B 2000-02-12 2000-02-17
```

Comment: Thanks a million! This seems quite simple! There is only a small issue. I would like *not* to include hospitalizations by other physicians in the same specialty that also involves the physician in the given row. For instance, we should see NA in the last row of the second column given that hospitalization 1 also involved physician 1 (in addition to physician 2). The desired values for the last row should be: NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 1, c(1,2), NA, NA, NA.

Comment: sure, no worries. We just add another exclusion to the `f()` function. See my edit

Comment: This is awesome, thanks so much! How can I then have the last column as a list so I can `unnest` it into long format. I converted it with `as.list()` but the `unnest()` function doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Another question came up. I am a little confused with the line of the code `s>date_end`. Although this is working and seems right, shouldn't we expect to have `<` instead given that we are looking for hospitalizations that happened before the row's end date?

Comment: Instead of pasting the matches together in `f()`, you can just return the matches themselves as a vector. Then, when applying `f()`, do this by hospitalization_id and physician id, and do a merge on the result. See my edit

Comment: As to your second question, we want the start date of the reference row to be AFTER the end_date of any other hospitalizations... That is we are looking for hospitalizations that end BEFORE the start date of the reference hospitalization..

Comment: Thanks @langtang!! When applying it to my data I am getting the following error `could not find function "."` even though I loaded the same libraries as with the toy example.

Comment: makes sure your frames are data.table.. try `setDT(df)` and `setDT(physician_spec)`

Comment: Awesome, it seems to be working now. Because my data is massive, I was just wondering if there is a way to make the code faster to run, by for instance searching only over the rows within the hospital of the reference hospitalization or/and have `other_phys ` defined as only physicians in matched specialty within the reference hospital. Does this make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247346/discussion-between-langtang-and-paulaspinola).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far, please experiment with other examples and the rest of the data set to see if it is what you are looking for:

```r
df <- data.frame(hospitalization_id = c(1, 2, 3,
                                        1, 2, 3,
                                        4, 5, 
                                        6, 7, 8),
                 hospital_id = c("A", "A", "A", 
                                 "A", "A", "A", 
                                 "A", "A",
                                 "B", "B", "B"),
                 physician_id = c(1, 1, 1, 
                                  2, 2, 2,
                                  3, 3, 
                                  2, 2, 2),
                 date_start = as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-12", "2000-01-20",
                                        "2000-01-01", "2000-01-12", "2000-01-20",
                                        "2000-01-12", "2000-01-20",
                                        "2000-02-10", "2000-02-11", "2000-02-12")),
                 date_end = as.Date(c("2000-01-03", "2000-01-18", "2000-01-22",
                                      "2000-01-03", "2000-01-18", "2000-01-22",
                                      "2000-01-18", "2000-01-22",
                                      "2000-02-11", "2000-02-14", "2000-02-17")))

physician_spec <- data.frame(physician_id = c(1, 2, 2, 3),
                      specialty_code = c(100, 100, 200, 200)) %>%
  group_by(physician_id) %>%
  summarise(specialties = list(specialty_code))

df_with_date_range <- df %>%
  mutate(date_range1 = date_start - 31,
         date_range2 = date_start - 1) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  left_join(physician_spec, by = "physician_id") 

#Below uses specialty

df_with_date_range %>%
  mutate(hospital_id_in_range = pmap(list(date_range1, date_range2, hospital_id, physician_id, specialties),
                   function(x, y, z, p, s) filter(df_with_date_range,
                                                 date_start >= x & date_start <= y,
                                                 hospital_id == z,
                                                 physician_id != p,
                                                 any(specialties %in% s))$hospitalization_id)) %>%
  unnest(hospital_id_in_range, keep_empty = TRUE)

#Below does not use specialty

df_with_date_range %>%
  mutate(hospital_id_in_range = pmap(list(date_range1, date_range2, hospital_id, physician_id),
                   function(x, y, z, p) filter(df_with_date_range,
                                                 date_start >= x & date_start <= y,
                                                 hospital_id == z,
                                                 physician_id != p)$hospitalization_id)) %>%
  unnest(hospital_id_in_range, keep_empty = TRUE)
```

It appears that for this data set, the specialty included and unincluded versions are identical, so you have to play around with it and see either if I have made a mistake or this is the case. I essentially just joined dataframes and then added another filter condition to the `pmap`.

Comment: Thank you, @dcsuka! There seems to be a typo I can't figure out why is happening. Hospitalization 4 (performed by physician 3) is matched to hospitalization 3 - physician 1 (row 3 of the original df) even though physicians 1 and 3 don't share any specialty.

Comment: I think the issue is because specialty is a list the dataset, and when filtering we want to compare all items in the specialty list informed in a fixed row with all items in the specialty list across each one of the rows in the df. We want to match rows such as c(100,200) and 200, 100 and c(100, 200), etc. I am trying to adapt the code to filter the rows for which the intersection is non-zero but I am not too sure how to do that.

Comment: Ah, it seems you found a solution that worked, and `data.table` is probably better here. Let me know if you need anything else! Best of luck with your project.