# More efficient match with data.table

Tags: r, loops, data.table, match, bigdata

I have a massive dataset with information on hospitalizations: it includes id of hospitalization, id of physicians, id of hospital, as well as admission/discharge dates. Given that one hospitalization may involve multiple physicians, each row in the data is identified at the hospitalization id - physician id level. A physician may work in multiple hospitals. There are 92M hospitalizations, 150k physicians and 6k hospitals in my data.

I have another dataset with information on physicians' specialties. A physician may have multiple specialties.

I want to find, for each hospitalization-physician ids, the ids of all other hospitalizations in the same hospital that were concluded in the 30 days prior to the start of that given hospitalization and performed exclusively by other physicians in the same specialty.

Consider the simple example below. The `sample` variable added to `df` flags the hospitalization ids which will have at least 1 other hospitalization linked to it according to the criteria explained above.

```
df <- data.frame(hospitalization_id = c(1, 2, 3,
                                        1, 2, 3,
                                        4, 5, 
                                        6, 7, 8),
                 hospital_id = c("A", "A", "A", 
                                 "A", "A", "A", 
                                 "A", "A",
                                 "B", "B", "B"),
                 physician_id = c(1, 1, 1, 
                                  2, 2, 2,
                                  3, 3, 
                                  2, 2, 2),
                 date_start = as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-12", "2000-01-20",
                                        "2000-01-01", "2000-01-12", "2000-01-20",
                                        "2000-01-12", "2000-01-20",
                                        "2000-02-10", "2000-02-11", "2000-02-12")),
                 date_end = as.Date(c("2000-01-03", "2000-01-18", "2000-01-22",
                                      "2000-01-03", "2000-01-18", "2000-01-22",
                                      "2000-01-18", "2000-01-22",
                                      "2000-02-11", "2000-02-14", "2000-02-17")))
df <- df %>%
  mutate(sample = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0))

physician_spec <- data.frame(physician_id = c(1, 2, 2, 3),
                             specialty_code = c(100, 100, 200, 200))
```

With the help of StackOverFlow fellows (link to original post: [Find set of rows in row-specific range with restriction at different levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379338/find-set-of-rows-in-row-specific-range-with-restriction-at-different-levels/73379633?noredirect=1#comment129611043_73379633)), I now have the following code that works perfectly fine. ****The issue is that the code takes forever to run.**** In the past 3 days it went over only 300 hospitals out of the 6k hospitals in the data.

```
setDT(df)
setDT(physician_spec)

peers_in_spec <- function(p) {
  physician_spec[
    physician_id != p &
      specialty_code %in% physician_spec[physician_id==p, specialty_code],
    physician_id]
}

f <- function(p, st) { 
  peers_in_spec = peers_in_spec(p)
  exclude_hosps = df_hospital[physician_id == p, unique(hospitalization_id)]
  unique(df_hospital[
    physician_id %in% peers_in_spec(p) &
      (st - date_end)>=1 & (st - date_end)<=30 & 
      !hospitalization_id %in% exclude_hosps
  ]$hospitalization_id) 
}

for(h in unique(df$hospital_id)) {
  
  print(paste0("Hospital id: ", h))
  df_hospital <- df[hospital_id==h] 
  
  tryCatch({
    output <- df_hospital[sample==1,
                .(peer_hospid = f(physician_id, date_start)), 
                .(physician_id, hospitalization_id)]
    print(output)
  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})

}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to make the code more efficient: either by further subsetting the original data before applying the f() function (for instance, by looping over each day-hospital and subsetting the data for the period prior to that day before applying f), or adjusting the code in some other way.

Comment: just wondering why did you change the previous code from a join to a loop through the hospitals?

Comment: It is a lot faster, because for each hospitalization id `f()` only goes over hospitalizations in the same hospital instead of going through all hospitalizations to check if the hospital matches (among other criteria)

Comment: no, I mean from the non-equi join we discussed previously?  if you did that non-equi join (which joined on hospital and used date range), then `f()` could have been modified to not look at hospital...

Comment: I did that, this is what `sample==1` is doing above - this tells us which hospitalizations have at least 1 past hospitalization matched it. Basically, for each of these sample hospitalizations the code goes over *all* hospitalizations to find the matched ones. By subsetting by hospital code, the matched hospitalizations are only searched for across other hospitalizations within the same hospital. Does it make sense? I checked and this made the code faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one alternative approach:

```
# load libraries
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

# set as data.table
setDT(physician_spec)
setDT(df)


# Create a physician match table.. for each physician, which other physicians are matched by speciality?
phys_match = physician_spec[physician_spec, on="specialty_code"] %>% 
  .[physician_id!=i.physician_id, .(mds = list(i.physician_id)),physician_id]

# Merge df on itself, using a join on hospital_id, and non-equi join re the start_date
k <- df[df[,.(hospital_id,h_id = hospitalization_id, date_end,e=date_end+30,other_md = physician_id)],
   on=.(hospital_id, date_start>date_end, date_start<e), nomatch=0] %>% 
  .[, .(hospitalization_id, h_id, hospital_id, physician_id, other_md)] %>% 
  .[phys_match,on="physician_id"]

# add speciality match boolean, and keep if this match is true
k[, spec_match:=other_md %in% mds[[1]], 1:nrow(k)]

# helper function checks: if the physician_id value (which is constant, so use p[1])
# is in o, then we return False, otherwise we check if among the rows where speciality matches
# there is a set difference of length>0

f <- function(p,o,m) {
  fifelse((p[1] %in% o),F,length(setdiff(o[m],p[m]))>0)
}

k[, f(physician_id, other_md,spec_match), .(hospitalization_id, h_id)][V1==TRUE][, V1:=NULL][]
```

Output:

```
   hospitalization_id h_id
1:                  3    4
2:                  4    1
3:                  5    1
4:                  5    2
```

Comment: Note that is `hospitalization_id` is not unique across the whole dataset (i.e. if different hospitals use overlapping `hospitalization_id`s), then add `hospital` to the grouping vars in the final code.

Comment: thank you @langtang! I have 2 questions: what does the `.` in `%>% .[whatever]` mean (for instance, when defining k for the first time)? Also, what does `.` followed by empty `[ ]` mean in the last row of the code?

Comment: How could I make the code discard matched hospitalizations that involved the reference physician (even if it involves other physicians in the same specialty)? Maybe adjusting `setdiff` to actually discard rows where there is a common element in both lists. PS: for instance, if I delete hospitalizations 2 & 3 for physician 2, the output matches hospitalization 2-3 to hospitalization 1 even though it should not because hospitalizations 2-3 and hospitalization 1 involve physician 1.

Comment: Answering to your comment above: `hospitalization_id` is unique across the whole dataset. I am just concerned that the output will be too large to be stored in a single object. I think I may need to loop over hospitals to make each object of manageable size.

Comment: the use of the magrittr pipe, followed by .[whatever] is a convenience for chaining. The `.` means the data.table object piped from the previous statement.   the .[] at the end is NOT necessary, except to show the result... :)  that is, when the final statement in data.table pipeline changes a value in-place, the output will not be shown.. The .[] forces it show.

Comment: thank you! Couldn't we chain in `data.table` using `[ ][ ]` instead of `%>% .[whatever]`: would these be equivalent?

Comment: yes, equivalent.  I almost never use the %>% .[] in my actual code.. I find it helpful only on SO for readibility

Comment: I solved the problem you noticed with "involved the reference physician".. see my edit.. I did this by removing the filter `physician_id!=`i.physician_id` in the original generation of `k`.. This allows us later (in the helper function, `f()`) to make false, any possible linkage between hospitalizations that involve the reference id

Comment: and yes, you could wrap this in a foeach %dopar% loop, to loop through 6000 hospitals

Comment: Thank you! I don't quite understand your comment `if the physician_id value (which is constant, so use p[1])`. Physician id can vary within `hospitalization_id` - `h_id` pairs. Also, why don't you filter for `spec_match==TRUE` when generating it in `k[, spec_match:=other_md %in% mds[[1]], 1:nrow(k)]`? This would make the data more feasible to handle.